# Prevent warning sheet after NSPersistentDocument rename

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsdocument, nspersistentdocument

Whenever my document is renamed , autosaving is blocked and the first save after the rename presents the pictured message.

[image]

Technically its not an issue as either button takes the user back to a autosavable state but it is confusing for my users.

I have tried hooking the method

```
-(void)moveToURL:(NSURL *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completionHandler
{
    void(^takeoverblock)(NSError *error) = ^(NSError *error){

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(error);
        }

        if (!error) {

            [self updateChangeCountWithToken:[self changeCountTokenForSaveOperation:NSAutosaveInPlaceOperation] forSaveOperation:NSAutosaveInPlaceOperation];
        }

    };

    [super moveToURL:url completionHandler:takeoverblock];
}
```

and using various flavours of `updateChangeCount:` and `updateChangeCountWithToken:`  but the warning consistently appears.

How do I put the document in a state where it resumes standard autosave behaviour after a rename/move.?

Comment: Who or what did rename or move the file?

Comment: The user via title bar or file menu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer [via a friendly Apple engineer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/917612#917612) is this appears when the modificationDate on the underlying  sqlite file is different to the `fileModificationDate` property on the `NSPersistentDocument` instance so to resolve reset the `fileModificationDate` after the move

override `moveToUrl:` like this

```
-(NSDate *)modDateForURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:[url path] error:NULL];
    return dict[NSFileModificationDate];
}


-(void)moveToURL:(NSURL *)url completionHandler:(void (^)(NSError *))completionHandler
{

    void(^takeoverblock)(NSError *error) = ^(NSError *error){

        if (completionHandler) {
            completionHandler(error);
        }

        if (!error) {

            self.fileModificationDate = [self modDateForURL:self.fileURL];

        }

    };

    [super moveToURL:url completionHandler:takeoverblock];
}
```